# Translucent background like iOS/OS X and Windows 10 startmenu in WPF apps

Tags: c#, wpf, translucency

iOS, MAC OS X and now Windows 10 support translucent background. Is there a documented API in Windows 10 to extend this effect in WPF window? What I want is part of my app window to be translucent, but content I put there should still be legible. see [example](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/osx_design_view_facetime-610x382.jpg)

Please not that this is not the same as changing Opacity property on a control, what I want is transparency plus blur on top of primary coloured hotspots in the background.[image]

Comment: I think you have seen different solutions for opacity so you are missing blur. what about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742795(v=vs.90).aspx?

Comment: @JensHorstmann thanks for commenting. Couple issues here, the blur is spread out consistently and not aware of the colours in the background. If I add this effect to the Window, everything inside the window becomes blur too!

Answer (score 0):

I have darkened and blurred backgrounds before when having a dialog appear over the top.

The way I would do it is use a VisualBrush with blur effect to create the blurred visual (I was blurring a UserControl that was not blurred before the dialog appeared) and then I would place a Canvas with black background and reduced opacity over the top to darken it.

```
<VisualBrush>
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
            <Image Source="Images\myImage.png">
                <Image.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

My code does not exactly describe what you want to achieve, but the technique of using the VisualBrush with blur effect is the key.

P.S. I think the iOS version of this looks awful and I doubt that there is any transparency in their solution, they probably just show a blurred image.

Comment: This might work for overlays within an app. What I need is that part of the main window to have the translucent effect (bit like AERO in VISTA) while content on top of it is still legible.

Comment: Yes, so use the part you want blurred in the VisualBrush, use the brush on a background of a Canvas/Grid to create the blur effect and then you can put your legible content over the top of the blurred control....